# Home page merely shows a directory listing

Tags: windows, iis

Thread title: "phpmyadmin shows a directory listing" (this title was unacceptable to the site, so I will use a less clear title copied from another thread that was successfully posted.)

I am using IIS 10. This is on a Windows 10 operating system. I am not using Apache. I copied the web directory over from another computer. PHP works fine.
I don't have any problems with any home pages (not even sure what is meant by that but it's in the thread title), just phpmyadmin isn't working correctly.

Comment: Are you calling the website just by it's address or are you including the name of the default page? If it's just by the address then you either need to include the page name or if you just want it accessible by the web address only, you might need to set the default page. In iis7 it's as follows - hopefully the same as iis10 ......Administrative Tools-> IIS Manager -> You Server Name -> Your site name -> Under HTTP features -> Default document -> Add MyDefaultPage.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Update to my comment .. this should work under iis10

1. Open the run dialog by pressing Windowskey+r
2. type inetmgr and press enter.
3. Click "Sites" in the list on the left
4. Click on your site
5. In the middle window, double click "Default document"
6. add and remove document names to your heart's content :)